# Checking event entries/writing to event log only once

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How do i read the last entered event log or is there any other way to limit to write only once the same event? This piece of code will help, but is there any other approach available?

```
EventLog eventLog;

eventLog = new EventLog();

eventLog.Log = eventLogName;

eventLog.Source = sourceName;

foreach (EventLogEntry log in eventLog.Entries)
{
    //log.Source - do your stuff
}
```

Comment: The snippet you provided is confusing.. That foreach will never do anything since there are no entries in your eventLog object.

Comment: (1) Do you want the last entered log? (2) What is your code snippet supposed to do and what does this have to do with anything : `is there any other way to limit to write only once the same event`

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent article on *Reading and Writing* to the *Event Log*.

> Use the Entries member when reading from the event log.
>
> Because the property is read-only, you cannot modify an entry or write
>   to the log using Entries. Instead, specify a Source and call
>   WriteEntry to write a new log entry. You can use Entries to count the
>   number of entries in the event log, and view each EventLogEntry in the
>   collection. Use the indexed Item member to retrieve information about
>   a specific entry, such as Message, Category, TimeWritten, or
>   EntryType.
>
> It is not necessary to specify a Source when only reading from a log.
>   You can specify only the Log name and MachineName (server computer
>   name) properties for the EventLog instance. In either case, the
>   Entries member is automatically populated with the event log's list of
>   entries. You can select the appropriate index for an item in this list
>   to read individual entries.
>
> An important distinction between reading and writing log entries is
>   that it is not necessary to explicitly call a read method. After the
>   Log and MachineName are specified, the Entries property is
>   automatically populated. If you change the value of the Log or
>   MachineName property, the Entries property is repopulated the next
>   time you read it.

An example would be:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class MySample{

    public static void Main(){

        EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
        myLog.Log = "MyNewLog";                      
        foreach(EventLogEntry entry in myLog.Entries){
            Console.WriteLine("\tEntry: " + entry.Message);
        }    
    }       
}
```

You'll obviously want to create a method that will be able to filter or sort out your request based on certain criteria to help limit your choices.  Hopefully this helps.

You may encounter certain permission issues; as they are tied into an *Administrator Category* with the *EventLogPermissionAccess.Administer*.

The information provided is directly from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries.aspx).